# Nach welcher Definition ist Ungemeinschaftlichkeit das längste deutsche Wort?

Tags: vocabulary, curiosity

Irgendwo habe ich mal gelesen, dass *Un­gemein­schaft­lich­keit* das längste deutsche Wort sei, wenn man die Kriterien hierfür so wähle, dass beliebig lange Wörter unzulässig seien.

Wie genau diese Kriterien aussehen, weiß ich nicht mehr, aber es liegt nahe, dass:

- Wortkomposition ausgeschlossen ist (sonst wären beliebig lange Wörter zulässig und bereits *Fuß­ball­welt­meister­schaft* schlüge *Un­gemein­schaft­lich­keit*).
- Eine willkürliche Anhäufung von Prä- und Suffixen ist ausgeschlossen ist (z. B. in *Anti­un­gemein­schaft­lich­keit*), z. B. durch die Forderung, dass das Wort in einem Wörterbuch stehen müsse.
- Eigennamen ausgeschlossen sind, sonst wäre z. B. *[Llanfairpwll­gwyngyllgogery­chwyrndrobwll­llan­tysilio­gogogoch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch)* klar länger.

Aber dann gibt es immer noch Wörter wie *[Tran­subs­tan­tia­tio­na­list](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transsubstantiation),* das einen Buchstaben länger ist und bei dem mir nur ein radikaler Ausschluss von Fremdwörtern einfiele, um es aus der Konkurrenz zu nehmen.

Meine Fragen lautet daher: **Gibt es irgendeine sinnvolle Definition des längsten deutschen Wortes, nach der *Un­gemein­schaft­lich­keit* gewinnt?**

Comment: Mit zwei "s" geschrieben ist es sogar um zwei länger (falls ich mich nicht verzählt habe), man könnte aber meinen, dass *Transsubstantiatonalist* zwei Vorsilben hat. Zusätzlich scheint mir die Erweiterung *-alist* etwas gezwungen, wie zB bei *Traktionalist*.

Comment: Da "Ungemenschaftlichkeit" selber eine Vorsilbe hat, scheinen mir die Kriterien gesucht. Diese Vorsilbe soll erlaubt sein, andere nicht? Ich glaube, ich kann zu jedem Wort Kriterien finden, so dass es zu den längsten gehört.

Comment: @PMF: Deswegen schrieb ich ja auch, dass Vorsilben nicht generell auszuschließen seien, sondern es ein Kriterium geben müsse, dass eine unendliche Anhäufung von Vorsilben ausschließe. So oder so ist das alles nur eine Schilderung von der offensichtlichen Probleme und naheliegender Lösungen. Das heißt nicht, dass diese Lösungen in Stein gemeißelt sind. Beachte außerdem, dass die Kriterien ansatzweise sinnvoll sein sollen.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Siehe den vorherigen Kommentar bzgl. der Vorsilben. Es gibt auch noch weitere Worte aus dem Dunstkreis der *Transubstantiation,* die *Ungemeinschaftlichkeit* schlügen, z. B. *Transubstantiationalismus.*

Comment: Auch da scheint mir das Wort konstruiert - also ohne (etablierte) Bedeutung.

Comment: Siehst Du eine Chance, eine Kriterienmenge zu definieren, die _Ungemeinschaftlichkeit_ zuläßt, aber _[Zusammenhangslosigkeit](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zusammenhangslosigkeit) ausschließt? Andernfalls wäre U. jedenfalls nicht das alleinige längste Wort.

Comment: @Matthias... Zwischenmenschlichkeit auch

Comment: Mit "Überdurchschnittlichkeit" dürfte die Theorie dann widerlegt sein.

Comment: Ich meine natürlich "Unterdurchschnittlichkeit" (25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die einzige Möglichkeit wäre zu sagen, dass nur genau 1 Teil des Wortes nicht allein stehen können darf. Ungemeinschaftlichkeit besteht nur aus „gemein“, kombiniert mit einer Reihe von Vor- und Nachsilben. Und es muss Teil des generellen Sprachschatzes sein. Da kann man dann natürlich wunderbar streiten, doch ich denke, dass man „Transblahblah“ so schon ausschließen kann. (Ich würde mal sagen 90 % der Deutschmuttersprachler kennen dieses Wort nicht.) 
Wörter wie „Zusammenhangslosigkeit“ oder „Unterdurchschnittlichkeit“ haben mindestens zwei Teile, die allein stehen können.
Allerdings halte ich eine solche Definition für wenig hilfreich und sinnvoll, da die Randbedingungen immer dazuerklärt werden müssen. 
Eine Definition wie „längstes Wort ohne ‚e‘“ ist auch technisch gesehen sinnvoll. In der Praxis allerdings nicht.